# Removing substring from string using Regex javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string in javascript like this:

```
frmSearch=FeeType=RecordingSpend:LoginID=:PersonCalled=:FeeAmount=22.234567:Paid=
```

I want to remove `:FeeAmount=22.234567` part from this string using `Regex` or `string.replace`.

It can be empty like this:

```
frmSearch=FeeType=RecordingSpend:LoginID=:PersonCalled=:FeeAmount=:Paid=
```

or it can contain any value

I tried this:

> var str= frmSearch.substr(frmSearch.indexOf(":FeeAmount"),
>   frmSearch.indexOf(":Paid="));

How can I do it using regex?

Comment: I have been trying substring and string.replace combination but they don't work

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: Show the effort, so people can help you figure out where you went wrong (and so this doesn't look like a "please write this for me" question).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - It should've worked with `.substring()` or `.slice()`, both of which take a start and end index, but `.substr()` takes a start and length. DotnetSparrow - is your desired output the original string minus that part (as assumed by the answers jcsanyi and I posted), or is the `FeeAmount=...` the part you want to _keep_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var frmSearch = "FeeType=RecordingSpend:LoginID=:PersonCalled=:FeeAmount=22.234567:Paid=";
frmSearch = frmSearch.replace(/(^|:)FeeAmount=[^:]*/,'$1FeeAmount=');
```

...will leave `FeeAmount=` in the string. To remove it completely:

```
frmSearch = frmSearch.replace(/(^|:)FeeAmount=[^:]*/,'');
```

Comment: My understanding is that the second example in the question is a second possible input, not the expected output.

Comment: @nnnnn what does it mean by (^|:) and [^:]* ?

Comment: There's plenty of [JS regex documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) available.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: `(^|:)FeeAmount` = Match `FeeAmount` at the beginning of the string (`^`), or after a `:`. The `[^:]*` means "zero or more characters that are NOT `:`".

Comment: Note also my replace is slightly dodgy because it may leave a `:` behind at the beginning of the string. But I put the `(^|:)` part in to give you a hint to at least factor that in to your final solution.

Comment: You're attempting to account for the possibility FeeAmount is at the beginning of the string, but you'd be leaving behind a leading `:` if that is the case.

Comment: @jcsanyi - Yes. It wasn't a problem when I thought the idea was to leave an "empty" `FeeAmount=` in the string, but I don't have time now to fix the second version. (I'm off to cook dinner.)

Comment: @nnnnnn I tried this frmSearch = frmSearch.replace(/(^|:)FeeAmount=[^:]*/, ''); but it is not removing the Feeamount

Comment: @DotnetSparrow - double check that. This fiddle appears to show that it works. http://jsfiddle.net/HDTsw/

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
var input = 'frmSearch=FeeType=RecordingSpend:LoginID=:PersonCalled=:FeeAmount=22.234567:Paid=';
var output = input.replace(/:FeeAmount=[0-9.]*/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the question, the matching regex rule may be

```
':FeeAmount=[^:]*'
```